# Creating a fixed row height/auto column count grid layout with css grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to create the following layout with css grid:

[image: grid-example]

What I have tried so far looks as follows:

```
.grid {
    padding: 16px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, 200px);
}

img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

but I am having trouble making the column count dynamic. Is it not possible at all?

Comment: You can define a fixed height for the rows ` grid-auto-rows: 150px;` and this for the columns `grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill,150px);` the max width for the columns will be 150px, you might see some overlaps, if so you need `max-width:100%`

Comment: Please provide enough code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS grid isn't a good fit for the layout you want. Luckily you can use flexbox to achieve something similar:

```
.grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

img {
    flex: 1;
    height: 200px; /* or whatever fixed height you need */
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Here's a Codepen: https://codepen.io/wiiiiilllllll/pen/ZRMxpo